# Dynamic Second Largest Data in Excel INDEX formula

Tags: excel, formula, excel-2016

Is it possible to adjust this formula in the way, that it shows me the data not from the largest, but from the second-largest item? Otherwise it shows me the „Total Sum“ :-)

Sure, I can adjust the data range manually, but I would rather have it dynamic, if possible.

`=INDEX(A$7:A$47;MATCH(LARGE(F$7:F$47+ROW($7:$47)%%%;ROW(A1));F$7:F$47+ROW($7:$47)%%%;0))`

Comment: Change `Row(A1)` to `2`

Comment: @Scott Craner Thank you so much! Now i understand, where it was hidden :-) I would like to accept your solution as a helpful one. How can I do it? Sorry, I am really quite new here :-)